# Grails - Pooled Connection closed

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am currently running grails 2.3.3 with 'in memory' H2 database. I regularly get a 'Pooled connection has already been closed' error when trying to bring up a specific view. It is always the same view but is intermittent as sometimes the view will appear successfully.

Here are the error messages in the log:

> PooledConnection has already been closed.. Stacktrace follows:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: could not load an entity: [homevu1.MusicShr#97]
>    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
>    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
>    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [homevu1.MusicShr#97]
>    at C__grails_workspace_rel_3_1_0_HomeVu1_grails_app_views_videoTemplateAdminShr_show_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(show.gsp:123)
>    at C__grails_workspace_rel_3_1_0_HomeVu1_grails_app_views_videoTemplateAdminShr_show_gsp.run(show.gsp:151)
>    ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
>    ... 7 more
>   rCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
>    ... 7 more

I have done some online investigation into this and perhaps there is a H2 pooled configuration setting I can try. Currently the settings are straightforward defaults -

Here is the section from Datasource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        username = "****"  
        password = "*****"
}

hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = true
        cache.use_query_cache = false
        cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {

    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }

//
//****************************
// using h2 devdb
//***************************
//          
dataSource_publish {
dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
url = "jdbc:h2:/dbmak/devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
}
```

I would welcome some suggestions?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable I don't know what's causing it to close the pool as it occurs in normal web browsing when trying to display a particular web page. Any ideas what is likely to cause this and what I should be looking for?

Comment: it was a joke. About something else, only some people get it.